# Error with up arrow key (press once, but more than 50 up arrow key fired)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am having problem with my up arrow key.
And, it is really very irritating.
When i press the up arrow key once, it just fire more than 50 up arrow key.
And overtime, i will have repeated occurrence every 2 minutes.
At low battery, this issue seems to go away. Weird.

Can someone help me?
I only have this issue when i reformat from Linux Mint to Ubuntu.

Comment: Problem solved, turn out there is a sticky substance under the 'Up Arrow' key, i remove the button and plucked out the substance.
Keyboard is back to normal=)